# What is in a Jamaican Chocolate Cheesecake?

Tags: restaurant-mimicry, cheesecake

I'm interested in making a variation of this baked [Jamaican Chocolate Cheesecake](http://www.cheesecake.com.au/baked-cheesecakes/jamaican-chocolate-296650) from the Cheesecake Shop. The description from the website is not terribly useful in identifying what the possible ingredients are:

> A smooth, baked chocolate cheesecake crowned with mouthwatering
>   chocolate shavings, and lightly dusted with icing sugar.

I've searched the internet fruitlessly for a "Jamaican Chocolate Cheesecake" recipe. There are a few other Jamaican Cheesecake recipes but they mostly seem to involve ingredients that are Jamaican (e.g. "Jamaican mangos") so I'm under the impression that the chocolate is Jamaican and it isn't a style of cheesecake. (Is "Jamaican chocolate" a thing? I couldn't find that either...)

The closest I can find is recipes for "[Jamaican Hot Chocolate](http://www.jamaican-recipes.com/jamaicanhotchocolate.html)" and "[Jamaican Chocolate Tea](http://cooklikeajamaican.com/chocolate-tea-jamaican-hot-chocolate/)" which involve some cinnamon and maybe nutmeg and other flavours.

Short of getting the people at the shop to give me the ingredients, which I doubt they would do, I'm at a loss as to what goes in this cake. This website has a non-promo photo of the cake, including the inside after it is cut: http://blog.stillaslife.com/food/jamaican-chocolate-cheesecake-from-the-cheesecake-shop/

Has anyone heard of this type of cake before and know what goes in it?

---

Unfortunately I haven't tasted the cheesecake. A choc-orange variety was requested so I'm just left guessing what else could be in it. I was mostly hoping it was a more common recipe than it is...

---

I ended up contacting them and it is just a normal chocolate cheesecake with a chocolate biscuit base. I inquired if it had rum or cinnamon or anything and they said no they just add cocoa to the normal vanilla cheesecake mix.

I'm going to award the answer to LoganGoesPlaces for the useful info and because their idea is very creative and sounds tasty.

Comment: I'm unclear from your question—have you tasted this cheesecake? If so, any comments on the flavor?

Comment: Have you considered contacting them to see what sort of ingredients it contains? Perhaps ask how it differs from a standard chocolate cheesecake?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't actually tasted it. It's intended to be  birthday cake and that flavour was requested.... Well a choc-orange variation anyway.

Comment: You should add the actual answer from the company as an answer not as part of the question.

Comment: i tried the jamaican Cheesecake from the cheesecake shop its ammazing and tried to search for the recipie but couldnt. the only thing i can add is there is a coconut flavour and flecks of dry coconut inside it or in the base that what im sue about.
thank you
raya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I've never experienced this cheesecake personally and the photo doesn't show anything at all "Jamaican" about it, I'd hazard a guess that the recipe involves rum.  The traditional go-to cake in Jamaica is a black fruit cake.  It involves soaking dried fruit in rum for an extended period of time and making liberal use of molasses for color.

If I were making it myself, I'd soak some dried fruit such as dates in rum for a few days.  Then I'd add rum to the cheesecake recipe and I'd chop the dates fine to put on top along with the shaved chocolate.

Comment: I have a difficult time believing that the company would include alcohol without telling consumers.

Comment: That doesn't mean there isn't rum flavoring.

Comment: You don't say rum flavoring. And according to the update to the question, there isn't any anyway.

Comment: I'm just approaching it from the perspective that if you want to prefix a product name with "Jamaican," the product should probably at least make use of an ingredient that is common in Jamaican products.

Comment: If someone knows that they cannot consume rum or they know that someone they are serving to cannot consume rum, I'd make the assumption that they already know about things like rum flavoring as an alternative.

Comment: Whether or not someone can consume rum is beside the point, what I am saying is that, as a corporate entity, it would be unlikely for them to omit the fact that there is rum (or even rum flavoring) from the description of the cake... I'm saying that your statement "*I'd hazard a guess that the recipe involves rum*" is unlikely to be true.

Comment: "I'm interested in making a variation of this..."  - Mike D.  While Mike was generally asking if anyone knew about that specific companies cheesecake, he was obviously open for suggestions.  Every cake I've had while in Jamaica involved rum in some way.  Including it makes more sense than the company's actual recipe, if what they told Mike was accurate.

Answer (score 0):

When I recently had this cheesecake, I was pretty sure there was rum flavoring and shredded coconut in the biscuit base.

Comment: Well, according to the company, there isn't...